# code works well in localhost but not on live site

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, localhost

I use wordpress as a cms. I need to offer a zip file download [to registered users] on every post, containing all the images attached to the post. Given is the code only from the main file "gallery-zip.php" ( [original code and rest of the files here](https://github.com/RalfAlbert/gallery-zip/blob/master/gallery-zip.php) ). The issue is it works only in localhost and NOT in the live server.

*PLUGIN CODE* :

```
<?php

namespace GalleryZip;

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', __NAMESPACE__ . '\gallery_zip_start', 10, 0 );

/**
* Invoke the plugin and load the needed classes
*/
function gallery_zip_start() {
// simple autoloader
$classes = glob( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/classes/*.php' );

if ( ! empty( $classes ) ) {
foreach ( $classes as $class )
require_once $class;


add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\add_hooks', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\enqueue_scripts', 10, 0 );

if ( is_admin() )
return;

// this is only needed on the frontend
GalleryZip::get_instance( new GalleryZip_DataContainer() );

}
}

/**
* Adding the needed hooks
*/
function add_hooks() {
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_galleryzip', __NAMESPACE__ . '\get_gallery_zip', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_galleryzip', __NAMESPACE__ . '\get_gallery_zip', 10, 0 );
}

/**
* Enqueu the JavaScript
*/
function enqueue_scripts() {
// load minified version if SCRIPT_DEBUG is true
$min = ( defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && true == SCRIPT_DEBUG ) ? '' : '.min';
wp_enqueue_script(
'gallery-zip',
plugins_url(
sprintf( 'js/gallery_zip%s.js', $min ),
__FILE__
),
array( 'jquery' ),
false,
true
);

// set JS object with params
wp_localize_script( 'gallery-zip', 'GalleryZip', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

/**
* Ajax callback for creating the zip-file and sending the url to zip-file
*/
function get_gallery_zip() {
$send_result = function( $result = '' ) {
if ( is_array( $result ) )
$result = var_export( $result, true );

header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
die( json_encode( array( 'result' => $result ) ) );
};

$post_id = (int) filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'post_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
$gallery_id = (int) filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'gallery_id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );

if ( 0 >= $post_id )
$send_result( var_export( $_POST, true ) );

$images = GalleryZip::get_images_ajax_callback( $post_id, $gallery_id );
$send_result( $images );
}
```

*TESTING ENVIRONMENTS* :

1. LOCALHOST : Runs on PHP 5.3.10 and with latest wordpress 3.6.1.
2. LIVE SITE : Runs on PHP 5.3.27 and again with latest wordpress 3.6.1.

**Things I tried and did**.
I tested the plugin on my localhost with latest wordpress 3.6.1 and PHP version 5.3.10 and used this line of code in single.php template `<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery]'); ?>`. It offered a nice zip-download link 'Get as Zip' on click and everything was flawless.

As soon as I installed the plugin on my live site it threw an error as the site was using an old version of PHP 5.2 and specifically due to a namespace syntax in the first line of the plugin code - `namespace GalleryZip;`, hence first of all I upgraded the PHP version.

Now, that I have it running on live site, it displays a link "GalleryZip" as expected on but the link does not prompt a zip-download and when clicked and just refreshes the page.

In order to rule out basic things I have tested in latest firefox, chrome and safari browsers, works as expected on localhost and not on live site. Wordpress related : I changed the theme into default twenty-thirteen ( tried it inside and outside the loop ) and also disabled all the other plugins, no change in result.

Firebug console displays `http://website.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 200 OK` on clicking the link, even on live site. I also asked for help a few weeks back from the original developer but have not received any response yet. So, if you may, kindly take a look at the code and let me know if this could be solved or correct me if I am wrong anywhere. Also please let me know if I should be definitely asking it somewhere else. Although I am continuously testing and in every way I can, a little helping hand is always appreciated.

Comment: Does your PHP errog log say anything useful? Does your app have rights to create the cache directory? Is it running out of memory?

Comment: @Ken Y-N Regarding errors- did not find anything useful or relevant at all. The plugin creates a folder upon installation 'galleryzip-cache' and currently the permissions set is 001 and there is nothing in the directory. Nothing is running out of memory I guess as I could not see such notice anywhere including the error log.

Comment: @KenY-N I changed the permissions to 777 and it worked perfectly. Thank you for pointing me right. Question - What permission would you advice it to set on in terms of making it a bit secure. And also please please write it as an answer so I can accept.

Comment: @IqbalMalik thanks for the suggestion. I have set it to 775 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please give 775 to the directory in which you are uploading images. 777 is extremely dangerous.